# Change textcolor minted in beamer

Tags: color, minted

I want to highlight the right part minted text simulating that it is a terminal, I would like the text "White text" to be white. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Example 1}
\begin{columns}[T] % align columns
\begin{column}{.7\textwidth}
Left Part

\begin{minted}[mathescape,
bgcolor=LightGray,
linenos,
fontsize=\tiny,
framesep=1mm]{c}
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  for (i=0; i<N; i++) A[i]=0;
    #pragma omp parallel private(tid){
      nthr = omp_get_num_threads();
      tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    
      A[tid] = tid + 5;
      printf ("El thread %d ha terminado \n", tid);
    }
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) printf ("A(%d) = %d \n", i, A[tid]);
  }
      \end{minted}
\end{column}%
\hfill%
\begin{column}{.18\textwidth}
Right Part
\begin{minted}[
linenos,
bgcolor=black,
fontsize=\tiny,
framesep=1mm]{bash}
White text
White text
White text
White text
 \end{minted}
\end{column}%
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

[image]